# Chrome for Mac OS Failing to load new MD5 Hash bundle

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome

This does not happen on Chrome for Windows but on Chrome for Mac OS. Instead of requesting new assets from the server Chrome tries to retrieve an old app bundle hash from a previous npm build and that app fails to load!

[image: Chrome Developer Console showing relevant 404 error]

This isn't making sense to me, the app-[hash]-bundle.js has changed, the hash has changed, that should bust the Chrome cache.

I am not sure what to do, I shouldn't have to do something like app-[hash]-bundle.js?refresh=[ticks] the hash is performing the same purpose.

Comment: just to make sure, did you also check disable cache in Chrome on the Mac that you are testing with? sometimes only that clears the cache completely

Comment: That wouldn't solve my problem anyways, trying to fix this for customers of my web app

Comment: I mean, if you just updated the bundle recently, it's likely that some people's browsers are still serving a cached version (old one). Also are you sure this is only on Mac? If possible, what happens if you test this on a mac that has disabled cache?

Comment: I can deploy a new bundle and this does not happen in Windows, if I disable cache in Mac Chrome the site loads of course

Comment: On Windows Chrome the old cached file is flushed a new resource request starts to the server

Comment: I guess it may happen due to caching of `index.html`. Since you may change the hash of js files, but browsers download a cached `index.html` which refers to the old scripts. Try to check your `index.html` code which is loaded first on Mac and Windows

Comment: That is  a good idea @Sergey

Comment: index.html being cached is the reason for that. If you are attempting to make your app offline first and hence need to cache index.html, then setup a `fetch` listener in your service worker which will remove the `index.html` from cache when a 404 occurs on critical resources.

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced this too and it's incredibly frustrating when the browser refuses to remove a file from its cache. It occurs because your browser has cached the `index.html` file. You can try a couple of things to get around it:

**1. Add meta tags to `index.html`**

Try adding these to the `<head>` of index.html, then clear the cache. This does not always work/isn't the recommended way of doing it.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

**2. Disable Chrome cache**

Disable the Chrome cache using this setting to prevent `index.html` from being cached.

[image: chrome dev tools disable cache]